# How can I access the arrow buttons that are used in the top right corner of the ios mail app?

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uibutton, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm wondering if the arrow images in the top-right corner of the mail app are accessible for use in my own segmentedControl. Is what would be even better is if I could somehow get access to left/right arrows as opposed to the up/down ones they are using.

Are these standard system UIButton types? How might I use them in my UISegmentedControl?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They could just be Unicode characters for triangle shapes.

Comment: Hmm, how might I go about using unicode characters to do the same thing?

Comment: Create an `NSString` using a method that exposes Unicode, e.g. `[NSString stringWithCharacters:someArray length:arrayLength]` or `[NSString stringWithUTFString:byteCStr]`, where you have put the appropriate encoded values into the source array.  On Mac OS X, use "Special Characters..." (Edit menu) to access Unicode tables, look up symbols and see their values.  For instance a black right-pointing triangle in UTF-8 would have a source array of: `char bytes[] = {0xE2, 0x96, 0xB6, '\0'};`.